# Is that a PHP date() bug?

Tags: php

Here is my code:

```
<?php

echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s",1477785600) ;
echo "<br />";
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s",1477789200) ;

?>
```

and result is

```
2016-10-30 02:00:00
2016-10-30 02:00:00
```

Why does date() get the same result with different timestamps?
Is that a PHP bug?

My environment setting is:

date.timezone=Europe/Berlin

PHP Version 5.6.30

Comment: Is that the day when you changed from Summer Time to Winter Time?

Comment: When I run your code I get this out put: 2016-10-29 17:00:00

2016-10-29 18:00:00. I'm guessing this has to do with time change like Barmar suggested. I'm on Canada/Montreal time zone. This output might actually be correct if time resets to 2 AM at 3AM.

Comment: @Barmar you are right!

Comment: Only happens on those exact timestamps. Its a summer winter issue for that timezone only

Comment: Add 1 to the timestamps and the duplicate time goes away

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's the correct output. In Western Europe, on 30 October 2016 it was 2:00 twice due to daylight saving time:

1. It was first 2:00 CEST (+0200).
2. One hour later, at 3:00, the clock was reset one hour and it was 2:00 CET (+0100).

Here's a slightly clearer [test case](https://3v4l.org/t9D1C):

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
echo date("r",1477785600) . "\n";
echo date("r",1477789200) ;
```

```
Sun, 30 Oct 2016 02:00:00 +0200
Sun, 30 Oct 2016 02:00:00 +0100
```